# Как переделать цикл в стрим?

Tags: java, коллекции, java-stream

Есть метод, который получает данные из класса и собирает в нужном формате в лист. Я реализовал это с помощью цикла, но необходимо использовать прелести JAVA 8 API, поэтому пытался заменить цикл на работу с .stream(), но пока безуспешно. Как это можно сделать?

```
private ArrayList<String> collectReport() {
    String timeFormat = "m:ss.SSS";
    String reportFormat = "%d. %s | %s | %s";
    int counter = 0;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ReportRecord dataRecord : recordList) {
        String name = dataRecord.getName();
        String team = dataRecord.getTeam();
        String time = LocalTime.ofNanoOfDay(dataRecord.getTimeDiff()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timeFormat));

       list.add(String.format(reportFormat, (1 + counter++), name, team, time));
        if (counter == 15) {
            list.add("—".repeat(60));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеет смысл создать отдельный метод для преобразования в строку элемента списка `recordList`, затем использовать `IntStream` для получения стрима индексов и преобразования индексов в строки.

```java
private String recordToString(int index) {
    String timeFormat = "m:ss.SSS";
    String reportFormat = "%d. %s | %s | %s";

    ReportRecord dataRecord = recordList.get(index);

    String name = dataRecord.getName();
    String team = dataRecord.getTeam();
    String time = LocalTime.ofNanoOfDay(dataRecord.getTimeDiff()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timeFormat));

    return String.format(reportFormat, 1 + index, name, team, time);
}

// вернуть только строки исходного списка
private List<String> collectReport() {
    return IntStream.range(0, recordList.size())
        .mapToObj(this::recordToString)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Разделители можно добавить отдельно.

В Java 16 и выше можно использовать метод [`Stream::toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) для получения *немодифицируемого* списка строк.

---

Однако, *если* строки-разделители *обязательно* должны быть в результирующем списке в качестве отдельного элемента, можно слегка модифицировать представленный метод `recordToString`, чтобы он возвращал стрим строк, к которым затем потребуется применить операцию `Stream::flatMap`.

Также, для получения конкретной реализации `ArrayList<String>` можно использовать коллектор `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` вместо привычного `Collectors.toList()`.

```java
private Stream<String> recordToStream(int index) {
    String timeFormat = "m:ss.SSS";
    String reportFormat = "%d. %s | %s | %s";
    String delimiter = "-".repeat(60);

    ReportRecord dataRecord = recordList.get(index);

    String name = dataRecord.getName();
    String team = dataRecord.getTeam();
    String time = LocalTime.ofNanoOfDay(dataRecord.getTimeDiff()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timeFormat));

    String result = String.format(reportFormat, 1 + index, name, team, time);
    return (1 + index) % 15 == 0 
        ? Stream.of(result, delimiter) 
        : Stream.of(result);
}

// вернуть строки исходного списка с разделителями
private ArrayList<String> collectReport() {
    return IntStream.range(0, recordList.size())
        .mapToObj(this::recordToStream) // Stream<Stream<String>>
        .flatMap(s -> s) // Stream<String>, вариант .flatMap(Function.identity())
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Слишком сложно для меня пока, буду разбираться.

Comment: С чем именно сложности?

Comment: Не понимаю почему именно такие методы в стримах используются, не понимаю хорошо их взаимодействия. Кажется, что там слишком много разных вариантов и поэтому сложно структурировать знания в голове. Очень сложно идёт изучение стримов. Думал, что понял, когда получалось простые операции над данными проводить, но как задача попалась посложнее - слёг не комп, а я. Думаю, сейчас отойду от основного пути и сфокусируюсь на стримах.

Comment: Пришлось использовать именно `IntStream` для потока `int` индексов, так как индекс входит в строку-результат для `ReportRecord`, поэтому в частности и применяется `IntStream::mapToObj`.  Также из контекста понятно, что `recordList` -- некое внутреннее поле класса, поэтому к нему допустим доступ из разных методов.  Если бы не было зависимости от индекса, можно было бы обойтись сразу потоком: `recordList.stream().map(this::recordToString)`

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение! Стало яснее.